# Django request.FILES is empty

Tags: django

I am making a file upload POST API request to django app REST interface. This request is made from another django app view which is receiving the file from the form.  I am using poster module

```
image = request.FILES['image']
from utils.poster.encode import multipart_encode
from utils.poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
register_openers()
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({'file':image.read()})
response = urlfetch.fetch(url="url",
            payload=datagen,
            method=urlfetch.POST,
            headers=headers)
```

Am I missing any headers?.  How django process request with multipart/form-data?
This is the error i am getting.

```
multipart_yielder instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

Answer (score 3):

GAE's UrlFetch cannot use the output returned by multipart_encode() for payload. `UrlFetch.fetch` is executing `len()` on the payload, and the payload returned by `multipart_encode` is a Python generator, which in general does not support `len()`.

The workaround is to create a payload string first, but it will use lot of memory for large files.

```
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({'file':image.read()})
data = str().join(datagen)    
response = urlfetch.fetch(url="url",
        payload=data ,
        method=urlfetch.POST,
        headers=headers)
```

Issue was reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=627).